# Emailing print_r with PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to email `$msg = print_r($_POST, true);`. When I receive the email the array doesn't look nice. Instead of 5 lines it shows it on one line. What can I do?

Edit: I can see in the email source that the print_r message is 5 lines. But not on the user interface (Gmail).

Comment: You could do some html formatting before you send the email. In other words, write your own print_r() function.

Comment: In response to your edit: newline != `<br />`. You could replace them with `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably getting it as HTML, in which case you need to surround it with a proper HTML tag:

```
$msg = '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
```

Where `<pre>` is the preformatted text tag.

An alternative to this is to use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) on the `$msg`, but it still won't look quite right as you want a monospaced font, which `<pre>` already gives you.

Answer (score 1):

`$msg = "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do:

```
$msg = nl2br(print_r($_POST, 1));
```

but im not sure..